# What will be the behavior of the index in these two scenarios in relation databases like mysql?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Let's say I have a table students with the following fields

> id,student_id,test_type,score

Consider these two queries

> select * from students where student_id = x and score > y
>   select * from students where student_id = x order by score

Let's say I have indexes on both student_id and score but not a composite index, what will be the indexes that will be used by the database? Will the query be able to use both of the indexes or whether at max one index can be used?

Let's say with the student_id index I am able to restrict the results in the query, will I be able to use the score index to sort or filtering?

or if databases chooses the score index to sort or filter first, will I be able to student_id index for student_id =x filtering?

Comment: MySQL could theoretically use two individual indexes for at least the first operation, using an index merge operation.  In practice, it doesn't seem to do that very often.  Just define a composite index `students(student_id, score)` and that works for both queries.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's optimizer would like the composite `INDEX(student_id, score)` for both queries.

Without the composite index...  The optimizer almost never uses two indexes.  The optimizer would pick between `INDEX(student_id)` and `INDEX(score)`.

But there is another wrinkle -- If this table is InnoDB, and if it has `PRIMARY KEY(student_id)`, then `INDEX(score)` implicitly has `student_id tacked on then end.  Hence`INDEX(score)` would be perfect for the *first* query.

Given two indexes, the optimizer looks at cardinality and various other things to pick between them.

[More on creating the best index](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Answer (score 0):

Well it definitely depends on your data set and database. Imagine in the students table if I have 100 different id's but the same student_id. The student_id index would be considered bad and the *Teradata Query Optimizer would be smart enough to choose a better one like score or id. (If using Teradata DB, but most have built in smart features like this). A Composite Index certainly wouldn't be selected because WHY? I think in this tables case wouldn't help fetch at all. The best way to select a good index is to ask okay which column can provide me a solid unique value that is inexpensive (Integer) and can eliminate a good partition or chunk of data if selected. But yes student_id would be the best index in this case. Plus the query that ends with "and score > y" would be quicker. Where clause is always seen first so dataset will be much smaller.